# computing difference between all pairs of numbers which is given in ascending order

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the different ways with which we can compute difference between all  pairs  of numbers among given numbers in ascending order. Say we have x1,x2,x3.....x8 where X1 X2..X8 ARE IN ASCENDING ORDER

We need to compute distance between all pairs of numbers ?

I got this code which is another way to do the above task ? If someone can make things more clear ?

```
                         // vector v to store all such numbers
                         sort(v.begin(),v.end());
                         long long res=0;
                         long long sum=0;
                         for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
                        {
                                res+=v[i]*i-sum,
                                sum+=v[i];
                                sum%=bs;
                        }
```

Comment: What are "1ll" and "bs"? Also, if you want "all pairs", then it doesn't matter if they are sorted.